# Proving limits in terms of epsilon delta questions

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

$ f(x)= {x^3}-2x+1. $
We want to show that $ \lim_{x\to 2} ({x^3}-2x+1)= 5 $.
So here, 
$ \lvert f(x)-f(2)\rvert = \lvert {x^3}-2x+1-5\rvert$ = $ \lvert {x^3}-2x-4\rvert $.

$ \lvert ({x^3}-2x)+(-4)\rvert \leq  \lvert {x^3}-2x\rvert + \lvert -4\rvert = \lvert {x^3}-2x\rvert + 4 $, by triangle inequality. 
I'm confused on what to do next for the $ \epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have computed, we have 
$$|f(x)-f(2)|=|x^3-2x-4|.\tag{0}$$
Now, we have 
$$x^3-2x-4=(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)=(x-2)[(x+1)^2+1].\tag{1}$$
If $|x-2|<1$, then $1<x<3$ and we can bound 
$$0<(x+1)^2+1\leq 16+1=17.\tag{2}$$

Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $\delta=\min\{ 1, \epsilon/17\}>0$
such that if $|x-2|<\delta$, then 
$$|f(x)-f(2)|=|x^3-2x-4|~~\mbox{ by }(0)\\
=|x-2|\cdot|(x+1)^2+1|~~\mbox{ by }(1)\\
\leq \frac{\epsilon}{17}\cdot 17 ~~\mbox{ by }(2)\\
=\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Just to confirm: We choose delta to be the minimum of 1 and epsilon/17 to ensure that |x-2|<1 AND |x-2|<epsilon/17 right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Therefore, if $|x-2|<\delta$, we have $(2)$ above and $|x-2|<\epsilon/17$.